# Default column value in database table is null after persisting a entity

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

[image]

From the image above you can see a column in the MySQL database (table Question) where I have a column that has a default value of 'Approved'. However if I make a new Question instance, set values on the object but not the status property it persist null in the status column instead of using the default value. Do I need to set the default value in the Java code instead? (Where I persist it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. When a persistent field of an entity is null, JPA doesn't ignore it. It sets the column to null in the generated insert/update statements. So you must set it to the default value in Java. The constructor of the entity could be the appropriate place to set such a default value.

Comment: I am using EclipseLink but the same probably applies.

Comment: Is it built-in, or configurable behaviour?

Comment: The same thing applies to EclipseLink.

Comment: Sorry, my mind often equal JPA to Hibernate. The same applies to EclipseLink. It's not configurable: a persistent field is made persistent, and its value is the value that is written in the database. This is a good thing, because it it weren't like this, it would have to refresh the entity after each insert/update to reload the default values set by the database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to provide the default mapping in your Entity class as hibernate doesnt support the default values(always), you can do it in two ways:

1. Use `default` option and provide the value in the @Column annotation. This is database dependent, need to check if this works for MySQL
2. As said by other poster, initialize your variable with "Approved" value in the constructor

Also very similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692808/from-hibernate-to-mysql-default-value-mapping-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Defaulting the value in Java is best.

You could also set insertable to false in your @Column, but then you object and database would be out of sync unless you did a refresh.

EclipseLink also supports returning field values from the database, but only on Oracle (unless stored procedures are used).